# How to make a click-through window in C++ without WS_EX_LAYERED

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to create a custom crosshair for a game called overwatch. My current solution is to create a topmost window that sits above the game while it plays using WS_EX_LAYERED, but WS_EX_LAYERED has such a huge performance hit to the game that I've decided it's an unviable solution. Are there any other ways I can make my tiny 4x4 pixel window click-through? (I already tried handling WM_NCHITTEST and returning HTTRANSPARENT/HTNOWHERE, both don't result in properly clicking through the window since it still takes the focus off of the window underneath.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Region window for this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145102(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I might have rushed the question a bit, I found an answer to my own question immediately after posting- Ihandle WM_NCHITTEST returning HTTRANSPARENT and I put WS_EX_NOACTIVATE in the extended properties during window creation.

Comment: @user2462027 I tried to send HTTRANSPARENT but I still seem to not click through the window. I'm so confused.

Comment: @HiteshKumarSaini The value HTTRANSPARENT works only for windows created by the same thread. So it won't work like the combination of WS_EX_LAYERED and WS_EX_TRANSPARENT.